# Verificar se usuário Maior idade usando Jquery(datepicker) & JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Precisando implementar uma função javascript  aonde calcula idade do usuário,informa um alerta caso seja menor de 18.Uso biblioteca do Jquery junto com JSP,aonde datepicker e carregado automaticamente dado uma annotation do Framework.

►Trecho do Código
✓ JSP

```
<n:panelGridBootstrap >
  <t:property name="dtnascimento"  />
</n:panelGridBootstrap>
```

✓ Javasscript

```
var esteAno = new Date().getFullYear();
$("input[name='dtnascimento']").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  onSelect: function(date) {
    var ano = date.split('-')[2]; // ano aqui
    var idade = esteAno - ano;

   if(idade<18){
   alert("Menor de Idade");
}
```

Comment: O que dá pra visualizar de início é que você não fechou a função do datepicker. Falta uma linha com });

Comment: Outra coisa é que você você tem que ter referenciado o jquery e utilizado esse trecho de código dentro de uma função $(document).ready(function(){ //aqui });

Comment: Por último verifique se há erro de javascript no console do navegador (F12).

Answer (score 1):

A tua lógica está correta. Sugiro juntares `changeYear: true,` ao datepicker e juntar `}` e `});` que falta no teu código, para fechar o `onSelect`, mas também o objecto e método invocado em `.datepicker({`.

Por uma questão de tipagem sugiro usar `Number` para fazeres as contas com *numeros*: `Number(date.split('-')[2])`.

```js
var esteAno = new Date().getFullYear();
$("input[name='dtnascimento']").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  changeYear: true,
  onSelect: function(date) {
    var ano = Number(date.split('-')[2]);
    var idade = esteAno - ano;

    if (idade < 18) {
      alert("Menor de Idade");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input name="dtnascimento" />
```

Comment: Apresenta erro ao tentar identificar o elemento 
Erro "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function[Learn More]",será devido esta buscando pelo name.

Comment: @RafaelLuz nesse caso acho que estás a esquecer de juntar a biblioteca jQuery ou o jQuery UI. Juntas os `script` que tenho na resposta.

Comment: acresentei o jquery-ui.js porém interferiu no meu projeto layout,mesmo assim não funcionou,como estou usando Framework que carrega Jquery e  Bootstrap,irei ver forma de fazer essa captura da data do datepicker via javascript puro(raiz).

Comment: @RafaelLuz cria um jsFiddle com as bibliotecas que estás a usar e com o código que indiquei para perceber o problema que estás a ter, e coloca aqui o link.